# Path connectedness and continuity

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that a topological space $U$ is path connected, which implies that for any $x,y \in U$, there exists a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to U$ such that $f(a)=x,f(b)=y$.

Using continuity of $f$, can I just simply assert that the preimage of open sets in $U$ is open in $[a,b]$ ignoring the condition $f(a)=x,f(b)=y$?

Comment: I don't get how you take the preimage of $U$ by $f$ when you're not sure you have $U\subset Im (f)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure that in the definition of path connected, the function $f$ is defined from $[0,1]$ and not $[a,b]$ ( guess what happens when $a = b$ ).

Anyway, you are just applying the definition of continous funcion, that is

> Given a function $ f : A \rightarrow B$ , we say that $f$ is continous if for every open set $U \in B$, the preimage is an open set in $A$

so yes, it's safe to say that

> In a path connected space, the preimage of an open set $ U \in B$ trough $f$ is an open set in $[0,1]$